# How to get PID_MAX macro?

Tags: c, freebsd

I would like to get the value of the `PID_MAX` macro present in the file `/sys/sys/proc.h`.

My current code (main.c) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sys/types.h> /* type pid_t */
#include <sys/proc.h> /* macro PID_MAX */
#include <sys/unistd.h> /* function getpid, getppid */

/*
gcc -Wall -Wextra main.c -o main
./main
*/

int main ()
{
    pid_t pidmax = PID_MAX;

    printf ( "Value = %d\n", pidmax );

    return 0;
}
```

Return the following error :

```
error: 'PID_MAX' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'UID_MAX'?
```

How is it possible?

Another method to recover the `PID_MAX`?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, assume that any positive `pid_t` could be a valid PID.  Everything else means your code could break when the kernel-internal limit is increased.

Answer (score 4):

There is no platform-independent method for retrieving the maximum pid value.
Under Linux, for example, you can determine the value through the `/proc/sys` interface

```
$ sysctl kernel/pid_max
32768
```

Under FreeBSD, the value is `99999`. If you look closely in `sys/proc.h`, you will notice that the macro `PID_MAX` is guarded by

```
#ifdef _KERNEL
...
#define PID_MAX 99999
...
#endif
```

This is, why you cannot (and should not) use it in userspace programs.

Answer (score -1):

The `PID_MAX` macro defines the hard limit of PID values by BSD kernels (such as kFreeBSD); it shouldn't be used by user space programs because the actual maximum PID value could be further lowered in the runtime, controlled by `kern.pid_max` sysctl.

To get such runtime limitation in an user space program, use **sysctlbyname(3)**; for example:

```c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        int pid_max;
        size_t len = sizeof pid_max;
        if(sysctlbyname("kern.pid_max", &pid_max, &len, NULL, 0) < 0) {
                perror("sysctlbyname: kern.pid_max");
                return 1;
        }
        printf("kern.pid_max=%d\n", pid_max);
        return 0;
}
```